# Post 18.04.1 - Deja Dup cannot detect the mounted & ready optical disk (CD)

Tags: 18.04, backup, deja-dup

The CD contents are visible in "Files" but "Deja Dup" is not detecting it.
In previous versions of Ubuntu, I could stop & restart the backup utility. The CD would then be detected and the backup started OK. . .  but not with 18.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working again by referring to the CD by directory path, rather than the single logical label by which it has alway been previously set

- WAS Storage Location : MEI_UDF
- NOW Storage Location : Local folder :    /media/kpsys/MEI_UDF

I do not know why this change was needed.